# Не работает ни jusctify-content: center, ни margin: 0 auto

Tags: html, css

```css
.footer-logo {
  margin-top: 69px;
}

.footer-info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-info-social {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px;
  gap: 12px;
  margin: 61px auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-info">
  <img src="img/Logo.svg" alt="логотип" class="footer-logo">
  <div class="footer-info-social">
    <a href="#" class="footer-social-link"><img src="img/facebook.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" class="footer-social-link"><img src="img/twitter.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" class="footer-social-link"><img src="img/instagram.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" class="footer-social-link"><img src="img/linkedin.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <p class="footer-info-copyright">© Copyright 2022 by Ranu Hasan</p>
</div>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRiGB.png]

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что что-то не работает?